# Controlling the positions of a views in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am trying to create an android app where I have a single relatively big button in the middle (the light blue in the picture) and it is surrounded by other smaller buttons as shown in the picture (some of small buttons might be visible or invisible based on some criteria).

I started with the RelativLayout setting the big on in the center and making the rest placed in relation to it, but it is a miss and the central button get shifted and doesn't stay in the center. I tried placing them in FrameLayout and used margin to adjust their locations, that worked the best however, the spacing changes on different screen resolutions.

So what is the best way to achieve such layout that will look consistent on any device?

[image: How it should look like]

Comment: I'm definitely looking forward to finding out the answer to this one :)

Comment: did you try PercentRelativeLayout from the percent support library? that might do what you want, if you know how you want these things to be proportioned in your view http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent

Comment: I just tried the Percent, in order for it to work correctly I need to change everything to using percentages including the buttons heights and widths which complicates things since I need to calculate the w to h ratio for all possible screen sizes in-order to keep the aspect ratio of the buttons.

Comment: @ootinii I am now using the `PercentFrameLayout` and it is the closest thing to what I want, not perfect though. Submit your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I appreciate it. Sorry I couldn't be more help on this one. One alternative is you could always just measure and layout your own custom view. Usually that's a bit more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's Percent Support Library allows you to use proportions to lay out your views, which may allow you to get closer to your goal.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent